# Yii2 how to I get user from database in findIdentityByAccessToken method?

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I need to set up JWT authentication for my Yii2 app. The authentication itself works fine, the token gets parsed and I can read it's data in my User model. But the problem is that I need to compare this data to a real user in my DB. So, I've got this method in the User model which extends ActiveRecord

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
    $user = User::findOne(['ID' => 1]);
    die(json_encode($user));
}
```

It's very simplified just to see that it finds a user. It does not and it always returns this:

> {"id":null,"userLogin":null,"userPass":null,"userNicename":null,"userEmail":null,"userUrl":null,"userRegistered":null,"userActivationKey":null,"userStatus":null,"displayName":null}

The data is not populated. But if I do the same inside any controller, like so

```
class TokenController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';

    public function actionFind(){
        return User::findOne(['ID' => 1]);
    }
}
```

It works great and I get the User object populated with correct data. 
Is it possible to get user from not within an ActiveController class?

Comment: I get an empty object from json_encode and the right one from var_dump. I think you have the object, but treat it wrong.

Comment: Probably. It was my first day working with Yii and active record

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know exactly what is wrong with this line here `die(json_encode($user));`
But it actually finds and populates the user and I can access it later via

```
Yii::$app->user->identity
```

so I can also blindly compare its ID and password to the real ones here